# Why function literal with single tuple argument accepts a list of arguments as well?

Tags: scala

I discovered this interesting "phenomenon" whereby if a function literal is defined to take in a tuple as its input parameter (). It can be applied to 
1. a tuple
2. a list of arguments of type same as the components of the tuple

Can someone explain to me why this can happen? Actually, i was expecting 2. to fail

```
scala> val foo = (x:List[Int],y:Int) => x.length + y
foo: (List[Int], Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> val bar = (x:(List[Int],Int)) => x._1.length + x._2
bar: ((List[Int], Int)) => Int = <function1>

scala> foo((List(1,2,3),10))
<console>:13: error: not enough arguments for method apply: (v1: List[Int], v2: Int)Int in trait Function2.
Unspecified value parameter v2.
       foo((List(1,2,3),10))
          ^

scala> foo(List(1,2,3),10)
res37: Int = 13

scala> bar(List(1,2,3),10)
res38: Int = 13

scala> bar((List(1,2,3),10))
res39: Int = 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I don't have reputation to add comment, but I suggest to look up auto tupling.

The reason

```
scala> bar(List(1,2,3),10)
res38: Int = 13
```

works is because the two arguments are converted into tuple (List(1,2,3), 10), to conform to bar's argument type.

There are compile flags to warn (-Ywarn-adapted-args) or disallow (-Yno-adapted-args) such behavior.

Answer (score 4):

You are a bit confused with the argument enclosing parentheses, they're not needed if the argument is a tuple:

```
scala> def f(x:(String, String)) = x
f: (x: (String, String))(String, String)

scala> f("a","b")
res9: (String, String) = (a,b)

scala> f(("a","b"))
res10: (String, String) = (a,b)

scala> f((("a","b")))
res11: (String, String) = (a,b)

scala> f(((("a","b"))))
res12: (String, String) = (a,b)
```

However,

```
scala> def g(x: (Int, Int), z:Int) = z
g: (x: (Int, Int), z: Int)Int

scala> g((1,2),3)
res13: Int = 3

scala> g(1,2,3)
<console>:9: error: too many arguments for method g: (x: (Int, Int), z: Int)Int
          g(1,2,3)
```